# Laravel sorting eager loaded data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the following query to get all companies for a certain event. And they are ordered by name

```
$companies = Company::where('city_id', 3)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

Now in my view i use eager loading to get all the persons that work for that company

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
    @foreach($company->persons as $person)
        <tr><td>{{ $person->firstname }}</td></tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

#### I'm trying to sort the persons by name but it's not working. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further query your relations in Laravel.

For example to get person by names in an ascending order.

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
    @foreach($company->persons()->orderBy('firstname','asc')->get() as $person)
        <tr><td>{{ $person->firstname }}</td></tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Perfect! Laravel keeps amazing :) Still wondering what the difference is between $company->persons and $company->persons() Thanks!

Comment: $company->persons returns an object of collection class which is similar to what $company->persons()->get(); provides while $company->persons() is an object of builder class which can be further used for database operations.